# ajuda com armazenar valor de uma variável local no python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, sqlite3

Olá, bem, estou escrevendo uma aplicação usando SQLITE e Python, estava tudo correndo bem até que tive um problema que não estou conseguindo solucionar, acontece que tenho uma db da fipe, então preciso carregar 3 combobox com marca, modelo e ano, então decidi fazer da seguinte maneira, no primeiro combobox eu carrego as marcas, logo a seguir carrego a escolha com um **".get()"**, com a resposta desse **".get()"** eu carregaria a  **_id** desta forma:

> **('SELECT _id FROM marca WHERE nome = {}'.format (respostado.get()))</b**

Logo a seguir com essa resposta carregaria os modelos com a resposta desse select, meu problema é que a reposta do **".get()"** fica dentro da minha **"def PegarMarca(self, event):"** e eu não estou conseguindo usar essa variável local, já tentei transforar ela em uma variável global, já tentei somar as string criando antes uma variável aberta e somando depois dentro da função, já tentei fazer de tudo que meu conhecimento é capaz más não consigo solucionar, alguém me dá uma luz, agora além de estar com o problema estou curioso também para saber a solução, vou deixar o código da aplicação (ela possui algumas partes incompletas pois eu já reescrevi mil vezes para tentar solucionar o problema, mas ela assim é melhor para vocês entenderem meu problema).

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import sqlite3

class Sqlite:
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.db = sqlite3.connect('fdb.db')
        self.cb = ttk.Combobox(master)
        self.cb.pack()
        self.cb['values'] = self.combo_input()
        self.cb.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.PegarMarca)
        self.cc = ttk.Combobox()
        self.cc.pack()
        self.cc['values'] = self.modelo()
        
    def combo_input(self) -> object:
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT nome FROM marca')
        data = []

        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            data.append(row[0])
        return data

    def PegarMarca(self, event):
        print(self.cb.get())

    def modelo(self) -> object:
        cursor = self.db.cursor ()
        cursor.execute('SELECT _id FROM marca WHERE nome = "{}"')
        data = []

        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            data.append(row[0])
        return data

root = tk.Tk()
Sqlite(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Essa classe é bem esquisita porque ela chama `Sqlite` quando ela não é uma instância do SQlite. Parece ser um formulário faz tudo, ou seja, recebe dados, manipula, acessa o banco de dados, ou seja, é tudo menos uma classe coesa. Começa por aí que facilita ter erros. Ou seja, consertar o erro que está pedindo só resolveria do jeito errado, se resolver. Quando começa errado, a tendência é tentar resolver com novos erros.

Answer (score 0):

A forma que está estruturado não facilita as consultas no banco.

Como não sei a estrutura da sua tabela vamos tentar simular.

Seguindo como exemplo a seguinte tabela:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `veiculos` (
    `marca` TEXT,
    `modelo`    TEXT,
    `ano`   INTEGER,
    `cor`   TEXT
);
INSERT INTO `veiculos` VALUES ('Fiat','Uno',2000,'Branco');
INSERT INTO `veiculos` VALUES ('Fiat','Palio',2017,'Preto');
INSERT INTO `veiculos` VALUES ('Fiat','Uno',1990,'Roxo');
INSERT INTO `veiculos` VALUES ('Ford','Ka',2015,'Amarelo');
INSERT INTO `veiculos` VALUES ('Fiat','Uno',2000,'Preto');
COMMIT;
```

Acredito que:

- Ao selecionar o combobox **marcas** o combobox **modelos** deve ser
  preenchido.
- Ao selecionar o combobox **modelo** o combobox **ano** deve ser
  preenchido.
- Por fim ao selecionar o combobox **ano** os veículos são exibidos (ou
  você pode por um botão que dispara o evento final).

Com base no descrito acima:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Exemplo Tkinter com SQLite"""
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class ConectarDB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conexao = sqlite3.connect('fdb.db')
        self.cursor = self.conexao.cursor()

    def buscar_marca(self):
        return self.cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT marca FROM veiculos').fetchall()

    def busca_modelo(self, marca):
        return self.cursor.execute(
            "SELECT DISTINCT modelo FROM veiculos WHERE marca=? COLLATE NOCASE", (marca,)).fetchall()

    def buscar_ano(self, modelo):
        return self.cursor.execute(
            "SELECT DISTINCT ano FROM veiculos WHERE modelo=? COLLATE NOCASE", (modelo,)).fetchall()

    def buscar_veiculos(self, marca, modelo, ano):
        return self.cursor.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM veiculos WHERE marca=? and modelo=? and ano=? COLLATE NOCASE",
            (marca, modelo, ano,)).fetchall()


class Janela(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        # Coletando informações do monitor
        largura = round(self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2)
        altura = round(self.winfo_screenheight() / 2)
        tamanho = ('%sx%s' % (largura, altura))

        # Título da janela principal.
        self.master.title('Exemplo')
        # Tamanho da janela principal.
        self.master.geometry(tamanho)
        # Gerenciador de layout da janela principal.
        self.pack()

        # Criando uma instancia do banco de dados (Abrindo a conexão).
        self.banco = ConectarDB()

        # Inserindo widgets na janela principal.
        self.criar_widgets()

    def criar_widgets(self):
        # Combobox marcas.
        self.comboboxMarca = ttk.Combobox()
        # Preenchedo o combobox com os valores do banco.
        self.comboboxMarca['values'] = self.banco.buscar_marca()
        # Evento que é disparado quando algo é selecionado.
        self.comboboxMarca.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.pegar_modelo)
        self.comboboxMarca.pack()

        # Combobox modelo.
        self.comboboxModelo = ttk.Combobox()
        self.comboboxModelo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.pegar_ano)
        self.comboboxModelo.pack()

        # Combobox ano.
        self.comboboxAno = ttk.Combobox()
        self.comboboxAno.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.resultado)
        self.comboboxAno.pack()

        # Listbox que irá exibir os resultados localizados.
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox()
        self.listbox.pack()

    def pegar_modelo(self, event):
        # Coletando o valor que foi selecionado no combobox marca.
        marca = self.comboboxMarca.get()

        # Buscando dados no banco e preenchendo o combobox modelo.
        self.comboboxModelo['values'] = self.banco.busca_modelo(marca=marca)

    def pegar_ano(self, event):
        # Coletando o valor que foi selecionado no combobox modelo.
        modelo = self.comboboxModelo.get()

        # Buscando dados no banco e preenchendo o combobox ano.
        self.comboboxAno['values'] = self.banco.buscar_ano(modelo=modelo)

    def resultado(self, event):
        # Coletando os valores de todos os combobox.
        marca = self.comboboxMarca.get()
        modelo = self.comboboxModelo.get()
        ano = self.comboboxAno.get()

        # Limpando o listbox.
        self.listbox.delete(0, tk.END)

        # Buscando dados no banco e utilizando um
        # laço de repetição para preencher o listbox.
        for veiculo in self.banco.buscar_veiculos(marca=marca, modelo=modelo, ano=ano):
            self.listbox.insert(tk.END, veiculo)


root = tk.Tk()
app = Janela(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Espero que lhe ajude como referencia ou para ideias.

Answer (score 0):

tudo certo?
Minha sugestão seria utilizar um atributo de classe, nesse caso o resultado seria visível na mesma.
Eu deixaria o método `PegarMarca` dessa forma:

```
def PegarMarca(self, event):
    self.marca = self.cb.get()
```

Onde `self.marca` é um atributo que armazena o valor que você deseja.
Porém devo aconselhar que refaça a estrutura dessa classe, pois está meio bangunçado.